# DataTables: Get Commas on Numbers and get them to sort correctly

Tags: java, html, datatable

I have a dataTable in a jsp page wherein I get data from the database. I have already done this (commas) by using DecimalFormat in java coming from the servlet. So now, I have commas on my number inputs in the dataTable.

The problem is they don't sort accordingly.

My table goes like this:

```
Location  Age Group  Both Count  Male Count  Female Count
Caloocan  1-2        1,200       600         600
Caloocan  3-4        200         150         50
Caloocan  5-7        4,501       3000        1501
```

Which means if I sort this in my current code, 200 just stays in the middle rather than it being the first or the last in the table.

is there a better way of doing this in datatables? Thank you.

Comment: Store it as a number without commas, and **format** the number for display.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch what do you mean?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch how do i store and format for display?

Comment: `DecimalFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#,##0"); System.out.println(nf.format(1000));`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch but I print it in the jsp page itself. I set attribute with the ArrayList from the servlet and get it in the jsp. There is a loop going on in the table <tr> in order to get all rows from the arraylist

Comment: Store it as a number use java code to format the number. See my first and second comments again.